# Why SELECT ... WHERE last_name = 0 returns all rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a simple table in MySQL:

```
create table t_users(
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```

I'm puzzled to discover that the following query returns ALL rows:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM t_users
WHERE last_name = 0;
```

Can someone explain that?
Thank you!

Comment: can you create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Fiddle wouldn't be required. Just try `SELECT 'somestring' = 0`. This will return 1

Comment: Regardless why it behaves this way, can I ask why your WHERE clause condition on a varchar column isn't in the form of `last_name = \`testString\``? (E.g testing against a string value)

Comment: `If you use a string in an arithmetic operation, it is converted to a floating-point number during expression evaluation.` and `If you use a number in string context, the number automatically is converted to a string:`. See [12.10 Cast Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [12.2 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html).

Answer (score 14):

In MySQL if you compare a string and a number, the string will be converted to a number which results in `0` for each string. And

```
0 = 0
```

is true.

If a string would start with a number - say `123abc` then it would result in `123`.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/5533)

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: Ist that MySql specific, where is it documented? Why is that so? Doesn't make much sense to allow that a string can be used like a number and implicitely convert it to 0.

Comment: "for each string" -> "for most strings". But you do clarify later in your answer already. :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That is what I learned in time by using MySQL. Did not see that behaviour on other DBMS. But I will look for it in the doc.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The fact that comparing a string and a number converts the string to a number, rather than the other way around, is not MySQL-specific. The fact that a conversion of a string to a number produces zero without any sort of error is MySQL-specific.

Comment: @hvd: yes, i've only just tested it on  MS SQL-Server, it produces an error that a remarks-field value could not be converted to `int`.This query ran successfully: `select * from tabdata
where  Remarks='1'
and Remarks=1` and returned all rows with `Remarks='1'`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is u are comparing string with numeric field.
Any field without a valid integer will equate to 0.
You should compare it as

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM t_users 
WHERE last_name = '0';
```